# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, webclient

When I try my program on my win2k8 machine it runs fine but on win 2k3 it gives me this error that error message

here's the code that' generating the error

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
wc.DownloadFile("ftp://ftp.website.com/sample.zip");
```

there's the weird part. if i disable the firewall on the server completely. the error goes away. but it still errors if i add the program to the exception list and turn on the firewall.

have search the web for days, couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try using passive mode for FTP. The WebClient class doesn't allow that, but FtpWebRequest does.

```
FtpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.website.com/sample.zip") as FtpWebRequest;
request.UsePassive = true;
FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponse();
int bufferSize = 8192;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("localfile.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    int nBytes;
    while((nBytes = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i use FtpWebRequest to download a file and save it to my local drive? I examples i found only show how to display server response.

Comment: it was a mistake, I meant nBytes... it's fixed now

Comment: See Stream.CopyTo() in .NET 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx

Comment: I am also getting this error even with FtpWebRequest in passive mode.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was already using FtpWebRequest, not WebClient, but I was getting the exception at the very *end* of the Stream.CopyTo() operation, when the file I was downloading was actually complete and intact. Rather than just coding to swallow the exception, this passive mode fix eliminated it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the complete exception, including any InnerException:

```
try
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
    wc.DownloadFile("ftp://ftp.website.com/sample.zip");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); // Or Debug.Trace, or whatever
    throw;    // As if the catch were not present
}
```

Comment: Post the whole thing anyway, for the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (no ftp) and a different solution

The production server environment had been made so secure that the server could not reach the URL.

Quick test is to use a browser on the box and see if you can navigate to the url.

Hope this helps someone.