# FTP Upload fails 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.'

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to **upload files to an FTP**, and have been doing so successfully until today. Here (at work) I've never had issues, but in production on-site we have had sporadic issues, but now **today all of a sudden it wont work 100% of the time** and I can't figure this out for the life of me.

I've tried nearly everything I could find.

- This is NOT a web service.
- I have increased my Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout to -1 for the FtpWebRequest.
- I have set the WriteTimeout and ReadTimeout of the stream I use to write the file contents.
- We have made sure outbound rules are set to allow the port we're communicating over etc and can confirm we can write/read using FileZilla from the same machine/network.
- The files are NOT large. They max at 1MB and are simple text files.

Below is the method I use. Let me know if you need anymore information.

```
private static void FtpUpload(String username, String password, String address, 
                              Int32 port, Boolean usePassive, String filePath)
{
    try
    {
        String fileName = "";

        fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        FtpWebRequest request = null;
        request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("ftp://{0}", address));

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            username,
            password);
        request.UsePassive = usePassive;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Timeout = -1;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Proxy = null;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Uploading {0}...", fileName));

        Stream ftpStream = null;

        using (ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            ftpStream.WriteTimeout = -1;
            ftpStream.ReadTimeout = -1;

            using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                file.CopyTo(ftpStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }            
}
```

[image: screenshot]

EDIT:

This code snippit works. Note when I update this snippet to use using blocks it goes back to failing. Could the use of using block be the cause?

```
public static void FtpUpload(
    String username, 
    String password, 
    String address, 
    Int32 port, 
    Boolean usePassive, 
    String filePath)
{

    string ftpServerIP = String.Format("ftp://{0}", address);
    string ftpUserID = username;
    string ftpPassword = password;
    FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filePath);

    try
    {

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServerIP);

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.UseBinary = false;
        request.UsePassive = false;
        request.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;

        // The buffer size is set to 2kb
        int buffLength = 2048;
        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
        int contentLen;

        FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

        Stream strm = request.GetRequestStream();

        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

        while (contentLen != 0)
        {
            // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
            strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
            contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        }

        strm.Close();
        fs.Close();

    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked your code and it did work for me. Did you set `usePassive=true`. This may be a reason for your exception (see [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875348/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receive?rq=1) )

Comment: This is the problem,  it works but under a particular environment it does not and it doesn't appear to be the firewall. And yes I have tried both true and false for usePassive.

Comment: Here's a twist, I took my code and isolated it. It behaved just as it did in the original project, worked w/ dev. environment, failed w/ prod. environment. NOW I found this example/solution [http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28693905/FtpWebRequest-The-underlying-connection-as-closed-An-unexpected-error-has-occurred-on-a-receive.html](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28693905/FtpWebRequest-The-underlying-connection-as-closed-An-unexpected-error-has-occurred-on-a-receive.html) took it and it works both here and there.. I don't get what I'm missing.

Comment: most examples that i know and found did use some kind of `Write(...)` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)) method on the stream - instead of `copy(..)`

Comment: I was to previously until this started. Both when I used write or copy yielded the same behavior.

Comment: I was having the same issue and found that the file was successfully uploaded to the server, so the connection wasn't closed before completing the upload process. A wireshark capture shows no issues related with the connection itself, it just seems to throw a webexception on success. As noted, sending blocks works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who stumbles across this, the solution contained in

http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28693905/FtpWebRequest-The-underlying-connection-as-closed-An-unexpected-error-has-occurred-on-a-receive.html

worked for me, you had to set the following to false

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(finalPath);
request.UseBinary = false;
request.UsePassive = false;
```

This solved the problem of the FTP upload working locally and failing once deployed to UAT